# F# Computation Expression to build state and defer execution

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I am looking to build a computation expression where I can express the following:

```
let x = someComputationExpression {
    do! "Message 1"
    printfn "something 1"
    do! "Message 2"
    printfn "something 2"
    do! "Message 3"
    printfn "something 3"
    let lastValue = 4
    do! "Message 4"
    // need to reference values across `do!`
    printfn "something %s" lastValue
}
```

and be able to take from `x` a list:

```
[| "Message 1"
   "Message 2"
   "Message 3"
   "Message 4" |]
```

without `printfn` ever getting called, but with the ability to later execute it (if that makes sense).

It doesn't need to be with the `do!` keyword, it could be `yield` or `return`, whatever is required for it to work.

To put it another way, I want to be able to collect some state in a computation express, and queue up work (the `printfn`s) that can be executed later.

I have tried a few things, but am not sure it's possible.

Comment: I can think of several possible solutions but how would you like to return the delayed actions? Should `let` in your example also be delayed? Can a delayed action return a value, in that case the following expressions might depend on it and the CE can't complete until the delayed action is executed

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `let`s could be delayed. The delayed work cannot return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to figure out a precise solution from the OP question. Instead I am going to post some code that the OP perhaps can adjust to the needs.

I define Result and ResultGenerator

```
type Result =
  | Direct  of string
  | Delayed of (unit -> unit)

type ResultGenerator<'T> = G of (Result list -> 'T*Result list )
```

The generator produces a value and a list of direct and delayed values, the direct values are the string list above but intermingled with them are the delayed values. I like returning intermingled so that the ordering is preserved.

Note this is a version of what is sometimes called a `State` monad.

Apart from the class CE components like `bind` and Builders I created two functions direct and delayed.

`direct` is used to create a direct value and `delayed` a delayed one (takes a function)

```
let direct v : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Direct v::rs

let delayed d : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Delayed d::rs
```

To improve the readability I defined delayed `trace` functions:

```
let trace m : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Delayed (fun () -> printfn "%s" m)::rs

let tracef fmt = kprintf trace fmt
```

From an example generator:

```
let test =
  builder {
    do! direct "Hello"
    do! tracef "A trace:%s" "!"
    do! direct "There"
    return 123
  }
```

The following result was achieved:

```
(123, [Direct "Hello"; Delayed <fun:trace@37-1>; Direct "There"])
```

(Delayed will print the trace when executed).

Hope this can give some ideas on how to attack the actual problem.

Full source:

```
open FStharp.Core.Printf

type Result =
  | Direct  of string
  | Delayed of (unit -> unit)

type ResultGenerator<'T> = G of (Result list -> 'T*Result list )

let value v : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    v,  rs

let bind (G t) uf : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    let tv, trs = t rs
    let (G u) = uf tv
    u trs

let combine (G t) (G u) : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    let _, trs = t rs
    u trs

let direct v : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Direct v::rs

let delayed d : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Delayed d::rs

let trace m : ResultGenerator<_> =
  G <| fun rs ->
    (), Delayed (fun () -> printfn "%s" m)::rs

let tracef fmt = kprintf trace fmt

type Builder() =
  class
    member x.Bind       (t, uf) = bind t uf
    member x.Combine    (t, u)  = combine t u
    member x.Return     v       = value v
    member x.ReturnFrom t       = t : ResultGenerator<_>
  end

let run (G t) =
  let v, rs = t []
  v, List.rev rs

let builder = Builder ()

let test =
  builder {
    do! direct "Hello"
    do! tracef "A trace:%s" "!"
    do! direct "There"
    return 123
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  run test |> printfn "%A"
  0
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the exact sort of guidance I was looking for. I'm no longer lost